# Get information from a TXT File

Tags: list, split

I have a txt file that has 7 columns and I am trying to extract data from. Essentially there is a column that has a lot of minimum values, a column solely consists of dashes, column of only maximum values, and a few others that I would like to break into their own lists (I think thats the way to go). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry I should have been clearer. I am using Python 3.5, grabbing right from the txt and using split actually. I guess I should ask where to go from there. I currently have it loading a file and using split(). End game I would like to be able to put each column into its own list so I can calculate averages, percentages, etc. Thanks again, sorry about the bad initial post, its my first time posting here.

```
file = open("year2000.txt")
for line in file:
    z = line.strip()
    z = line.find(" ") 
    min_sal1 = line[:z]
    min_sal2 = min_sal1.replace(',', '')
    min_sal3 = min_sal2.find('.')
    min_sal4 = min_sal1[:min_sal3]
    min_sal = int(min_sal4)        
    print(min_sal4)
    y = z.find(' ', 2)
    x = z.find(' ', 3)
    max_sal = line[y:x]
    print(max_sal)
```

After running this, I get a list of all min salarys like it should, however for max values I am getting just a bunch of blank lines. I also plan on putting each type of value into their own lists. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure "list" and "splice" are correct tags here?

Comment: depending on what language your are using, I would read the file, and use some form of the split command to break the fields up.

Comment: Is some sort of delimiter being used to separate columns?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your request is slightly unclear. 1) You haven't defined a programming language you want to do this in 2) Seeing your inputs and expected outputs are better than a description

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I am using Python 3.5, grabbing right from the txt and using split actually. I guess I should ask where to go from there. Thanks again

Comment: @StevenAndary Please include the code you have tried, some sample input, the expected output, and how your current attempt differs from the expectation